# withColumn function in scala not adding a contstant value to column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is my code:

```
val df=spark.emptyDataFrame
val modify2=df.withColumn("D", lit(750))
modify2.show(false)
```

it is returning an emptydataframe

```
+---+
|D  |
+---+
+---+
```

Comment: empty dataframe has no rows. withcolumn doesn't add rows

Answer (score 1):

that's the expected result. `withColumn` means spark will iterate on all the rows and then add a column to each. Since your dataframe is empty there's nothing to iterate on so no values.